# Configure Twig Plugin in Aptana 3

Tags: aptana, twig

Is there a way to configure Twig plugin on Aptana 3?

Here is the link to the plugin https://github.com/pulse00/Twig-Eclipse-Plugin

And it says it need PDT (PHP Development Tool) to run. But when i try to install both, it does not let me. It says, something like it can found some files.

So, it is possible to install Twig plugin in Aptana 3, and if so, can you teach me?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana 3 uses Eclipse 3.6.  That plugin requires Eclipse 3.7.

Regards, G.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for digging this out. Maybe try this:
Goto "Available Software Sites" in the "Install new Software" dialoge
Look for the checkboxes on the eclipse-related sites. Then aptana serches for the needed packages itself.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Twig plugin for Eclise's FAQ](http://twig.dubture.com/faq/), you now can use it in Aptana. I installed it myself, and I indeed can add Twig nature to my projects. But I actually can't configure the syntax coloring, for example, nor can I see my Twig code highlighted…

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple! Go to: Settings>General>Content types  text(expand), select html, and click ADD button - *.twig, and interpreter will colour your code form now!